# Mutating a character vector through case_when on specific values of a variable in a specific order

Tags: r, switch-statement, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(Letters = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E"))
meta <- c("foo", "bar", "baz")

   Letters
   <chr>  
 1 A      
 2 B      
 3 C      
 4 C      
 5 C      
 6 D      
 7 D      
 8 D      
 9 E      
10 E      
11 E
```

Here, I would like to mutate the character vector `meta` on to the letters `C`, `D`, `E` in the specific order of the vector.

I've tried something like:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(New = case_when(Letters %in% c("C", "D", "E") ~
                                   meta %>% rep_len(nrow(df)),
                               TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

However this starts the process of vectorisation at the top of the data frame, and `C`, `D`, `E`, are filled in the order of `baz`, `foo`, `bar` instead of `foo`, `bar`, `baz`.

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   Letters New  
   <chr>   <chr>
 1 A       NA   
 2 B       NA   
 3 C       baz  
 4 C       foo  
 5 C       bar  
 6 D       baz  
 7 D       foo  
 8 D       bar  
 9 E       baz  
10 E       foo  
11 E       bar
```

Desired output:

```
   Letters New  
   <chr>   <chr>
 1 A       NA   
 2 B       NA   
 3 C       foo  
 4 C       bar  
 5 C       baz  
 6 D       foo  
 7 D       bar  
 8 D       baz  
 9 E       foo  
10 E       bar  
11 E       baz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the number of times the character repeats in the 'Letters' column is the same as length of 'meta', a simple assignment would do it

```
df$New <- NA
df$New[df$Letters %in% c("C", "D", "E")] <- meta
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    group_by(Letters) %>% 
    nest %>%
    mutate(New = case_when(Letters %in% c('C', 'D', 'E') ~ list(meta),
                  TRUE ~ list(NA_character_))) %>% 
    unnest
```